# Inheritance in nested class

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested

I would like to have a class `Type`, and three classes `Integer`, `Real`, and `String` extending `Type`. Is it possible to have the three classes nested inside `Type`? So that I could write `Type::Integer int`, and get an object of type `Type::Integer`, which inherits from `Type`?

```
class Type {
   class Integer : public Type {

   };
   class Real : public Type {

   };
   class String : public Type {

   };
};

Type::Integer int;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without weighing into the soundness of your design:

```
class Type {
public:
   class Integer;
   class Real;
   class String;
};

class Type::Integer : public Type{};
class Type::Real    : public Type{};
class Type::String  : public Type{};
```

Side note: you can't use `int` as an identifier.